# Unity3d out of range error on a list when defining variables out of each element

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list with which I want to define three variables out of it.

```
YearText.text=CarInfoList[0].CarYear;
MakeText.text=CarInfoList[1].CarMake;
ModelText.text=CarInfoList[2].CarModel;
```

The list has one record set with the variable elements defined in a constructor script.
The first line works just fine and displays as expected, but when I try the second or third, it give me an out of range error. Anyone have some thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you populate your array? Looks like problem is there.

Comment: Seems like you meant to use the same object [0] instead of index 0,1,2. I guess so since first line is year, then make and the model.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said right in your question that there is only one record set...

you want this...

```
YearText.text=CarInfoList[0].CarYear;
MakeText.text=CarInfoList[0].CarMake;
ModelText.text=CarInfoList[0].CarModel;
```

Comment: @KenGordon Don't forget to accept answers if they satisfactorily solve your question - this signals to other members on the site that the problem is indeed solved.